# Como remover a última barra da URL

Tags: php, regex, url

Por favor, como posso remover a barra no final da URL. Por exemplo, tenho essas variáveis com as urls abaixo, mas não consigo remover a última barra:

```
<?php
 
 $url1 = 'http://www.site.com.br/domain1/domanin2/nome/';
 $url2 = 'http://www.site.com/';
 $url3 = 'http//www.site.com/diretorio/paginas/pagina/';

 $substituir = str_replace('/', '', $url1); // substitui todas as barras
```

Não quero substituir todas as barras '/' da url, apenas a última. Quando as urls forem substituídas eu teria:

```
  http://www.site.com.br/domain1/domanin2/nome
  http://www.site.com
  http//www.site.com/diretorio/paginas/pagina
```

Por favor, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção é usar [`rtrim`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

```
$url1 = 'http://www.site.com.br/domain1/domanin2/nome/';
$sem_barra = rtrim($url1, '/');
echo $sem_barra; // http://www.site.com.br/domain1/domanin2/nome
```

O segundo parâmetro indica quais caracteres devem ser removidos do final.

---

Ou, se você sabe que no final com certeza tem uma barra, pode usar [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$sem_barra = substr($url1, 0, -1);
```

No caso, eu pego da posição zero (do início da string) e o tamanho `-1` indica que quero remover 1 caractere do final.

Claro que assim sempre vai remover o último caractere, seja ele qual for. Se quiser remover somente a barra, então prefira usar `rtrim`.

---

E claro, a solução *over engineered* com regex:

```
$sem_barra = preg_replace('#/$#', '', $url1);
```

A ideia é ver se tem uma barra no final (o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$` indica o final da string), e substituir por `''` (string vazia), o que é o mesmo que remover.

A diferença é que nesse caso somente uma barra do final é removida, caso exista. Já o `rtrim` remove todas as barras do final:

```
$s = 'abc///';
echo preg_replace('#/$#', '', $s); // "abc//"
echo rtrim($s, '/'); // "abc"
```